# Serializable by extending with empty constructor?

Tags: java, serializable

TLDR: Is there a way to force to a subclass to have an empty constructor when the super does not?

I need to be to initialize a non-serializable class, `TravelTimeDataArray`,  from a serialized data container. The `TravelTimeDataArray` cannot be serialized because it does not implement the Serializable interface, lacks an empty constructor, and uses a non-serializable field of type `Link`.

```
public class TravelTimeDataArray implements TravelTimeData {
    private final double[] timeSum;
    private final int[] timeCnt;
    private final double[] travelTimes;
    private final Link link; //I'm not serializable

    public TravelTimeDataArray(final Link link, final int numSlots) {
        this.timeSum = new double[numSlots];
        this.timeCnt = new int[numSlots];
        this.travelTimes = new double[numSlots];
        this.link = link;
        resetTravelTimes();
    }

//getters and setters
}
```

My first thought was to extend this as a serializable class. Instead of using a `Link`, I can use a serializable String of it's ID attribute and add the empty constructor.

```
public class SerialTravelTimeDataArray extends TravelTimeDataArray implements java.io.Serializable{
    private final String linkId = null;  // I am serializable
    public SerialTravelTimeDataArray(){ } 

    public SerialTravelTimeDataArray(TravelTimeDataArray  ttDA){
      // intialize me using ttDA's data
    } 

   // Methods to serialize the fields.

   // Methods to populate super's fields from the deserialized data containers
   }
```

Since the super does not have an empty constructor, I get an error with the subclass's empty constructor. Is there a way to force to a subclass to have an empty constructor when the super does not?

Comment: You don't need an empty constructor in the Serializable class.

Comment: I know. I was hoping we could somehow override the default constructor of the super to use the subclass's empty constructor and thus make the subclass serializable.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A default generated constructor *will* use the base class's default constructor; nobody will call the default constructor of a serializable class during deserialization; and the base class doesn't *have* a default constructor, *which is the actual problem.* You need to step back and think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The Serializable Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a4539):

> A Serializable class must do the following:
>
> - Implement the java.io.Serializable interface
> - Identify the fields that should be serializable (Use the serialPersistentFields member to explicitly declare them serializable
>     or use the transient keyword to denote nonserializable fields.)
> - Have access to the no-arg constructor of its first nonserializable superclass

A no-arg constructor of a object's first nonserializable superclass is need to have access because it will be called while deserializing the object. Otherwise, an exception will be thrown. Note that serializing a object do not call its superclass's default constructor and no exception will be thrown.

If extending a class is not a must, you can consider using encapsulation like follows:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    private final double[] timeSum;
    private final int[] timeCnt;
    private final double[] travelTimes;
    private final String linkId;
    private final transient TravelTimeDataArray ttDA;


    public Foo(TravelTimeDataArray ttDA) {
        this.ttDA = ttDA;
        this.timeSum = ttDA.getTimeSum();
        this.timeCnt = ttDA.getTimeCnt();
        this.travelTimes = ttDA.getTravelTimes();
        this.linkId = ttDA.getLink().getId();
    }

    // Methods
}
```

If you do not need to access `TravelTimeDataArray` in your class, you can skip the field `transient TravelTimeDataArray ttDA`. Hope this can help.

Comment: Yes, this is the approach I have been taking. I was hoping there was a some Java black magic to get around the "no-arg constructor of its first nonserializable superclass" requirement. After all, we can use Reflection to expose private classes.